# Combine PySpark DataFrame ArrayType fields into single ArrayType field

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a PySpark DataFrame with 2 ArrayType fields:

```
>>>df
DataFrame[id: string, tokens: array<string>, bigrams: array<string>]
>>>df.take(1)
[Row(id='ID1', tokens=['one', 'two', 'two'], bigrams=['one two', 'two two'])]
```

I would like to combine them into a single ArrayType field:

```
>>>df2
DataFrame[id: string, tokens_bigrams: array<string>]
>>>df2.take(1)
[Row(id='ID1', tokens_bigrams=['one', 'two', 'two', 'one two', 'two two'])]
```

The syntax that works with strings does not seem to work here:

```
df2 = df.withColumn('tokens_bigrams', df.tokens + df.bigrams)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

**Spark >= 2.4**

You can use `concat` function ([SPARK-23736](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-23736)):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, concat 

df.select(concat(col("tokens"), col("tokens_bigrams"))).show(truncate=False)

# +---------------------------------+                                             
# |concat(tokens, tokens_bigrams)   |
# +---------------------------------+
# |[one, two, two, one two, two two]|
# |null                             |
# +---------------------------------+
```

To keep data when one of the values is `NULL` you can `coalesce` with `array`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import array, coalesce      

df.select(concat(
    coalesce(col("tokens"), array()),
    coalesce(col("tokens_bigrams"), array())
)).show(truncate = False)

# +--------------------------------------------------------------------+
# |concat(coalesce(tokens, array()), coalesce(tokens_bigrams, array()))|
# +--------------------------------------------------------------------+
# |[one, two, two, one two, two two]                                   |
# |[three]                                                             |
# +--------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**Spark < 2.4**

Unfortunately to concatenate `array` columns in general case you'll need an UDF, for example like this:

```
from itertools import chain
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, udf
from pyspark.sql.types import *


def concat(type):
    def concat_(*args):
        return list(chain.from_iterable((arg if arg else [] for arg in args)))
    return udf(concat_, ArrayType(type))
```

which can be used as:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(["one", "two", "two"], ["one two", "two two"]), (["three"], None)], 
    ("tokens", "tokens_bigrams")
)

concat_string_arrays = concat(StringType())
df.select(concat_string_arrays("tokens", "tokens_bigrams")).show(truncate=False)

# +---------------------------------+
# |concat_(tokens, tokens_bigrams)  |
# +---------------------------------+
# |[one, two, two, one two, two two]|
# |[three]                          |
# +---------------------------------+
```

Comment: how can i remove duplicates after merging both the arrays ?

Comment: @j' `df.withColumn('concat_no_duplicates', array_distinct(col('concat_(tokens, tokens_bigrams)')))`

Answer (score 6):

In Spark 2.4.0 (2.3 on Databricks platform) you can do it natively in the DataFrame API using the concat function. In your example you could do this:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, concat

df.withColumn('tokens_bigrams', concat(col('tokens'), col('bigrams')))
```

[Here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-23736) is the related jira.

Answer (score 1):

I was using Spark < 2.4 and the above solutions didn't work for me, was getting the error 'input to function concat should have StringType or BinaryType'.
This worked for me :

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.select("*",F.array(F.concat_ws(',', col('tokens'), col('bigrams))).\
                            alias('concat_cols'))
```