# Spark DataFrame aggregate and groupby multiple columns while retaining order

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following data

```
id | value1 | value2 
-----------------------
1         A       red
1         B       red
1         C      blue
2         A      blue
2         B      blue
2         C     green
```

The result I need is:

```
id |                       values
---------------------------------
 1      [[A,red],[B,red][C,blue]]
 2   [[A,blue],[B,blue][C,green]]
```

My approach so far is to groupby and aggregate value1 and value2 in seperate arrays and then merge them together as described in [Combine PySpark DataFrame ArrayType fields into single ArrayType field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37284077/combine-pyspark-dataframe-arraytype-fields-into-single-arraytype-field)

```
df.groupBy(["id"]).agg(*[F.collect_list("value1"), F.collect_list("value2")])
```

However since order is not guaranteed in `collect_list()` (see [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-16207)), how can I make sure value1 and value2 are both matched to the correct values?

This could potentially lead to two lists with different order and subsequent merging would match wrong values?

Comment: I would pack the two values in a stuct before collecting (works from Spark 2.0 onwards, at least in the scala api)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As commented by @Raphael, you can combine *value1* and *value2* columns into a single `struct` type column firstly, and then `collect_list`:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

(df.withColumn('values', F.struct(df.value1, df.value2))
   .groupBy('id')
   .agg(F.collect_list('values').alias('values'))).show()

+---+--------------------+
| id|              values|
+---+--------------------+
|  1|[[A,red], [B,red]...|
|  2|[[A,blue], [B,blu...|
+---+--------------------+
```