# Lateral view explode strange behaviour

Tags: pyspark

I am concatenating two array columns and convert them back to array.  Now when I apply explode, nothing is happening.  Using Spark 2.3.  Is there anything weird here?

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1,25,['A','B','B','C'],['A','B','B','C']),(1,20,['A','A','B','C'],['A','B','B','C']),(1,20,['A','C','B','C'],['A','B','B','C']),(2,26,['X','Y','Z','C'],['A','B','B','C'])],['id','age','one','two'])
+---+---+------------+------------+
| id|age|         one|         two|
+---+---+------------+------------+
|  1| 25|[A, B, B, C]|[A, B, B, C]|
|  1| 20|[A, A, B, C]|[A, B, B, C]|
|  1| 20|[A, C, B, C]|[A, B, B, C]|
|  2| 26|[X, Y, Z, C]|[A, B, B, C]|
+---+---+------------+------------+

>>> df.createOrReplaceTempView('df')
>>> df2 = spark.sql('''select id,age, array(concat_ws(',', one, two)) as three from df''')
>>> df2.show()
+---+---+-----------------+
| id|age|            three|
+---+---+-----------------+
|  1| 25|[A,B,B,C,A,B,B,C]|
|  1| 20|[A,A,B,C,A,B,B,C]|
|  1| 20|[A,C,B,C,A,B,B,C]|
|  2| 26|[X,Y,Z,C,A,B,B,C]|
+---+---+-----------------+

>>> df2.createOrReplaceTempView('df2')
>>> spark.sql('''select id, age, four from df2 lateral view explode(three) tbl as four''').show() //not exploding
+---+---+---------------+
| id|age|           four|
+---+---+---------------+
|  1| 25|A,B,B,C,A,B,B,C|
|  1| 20|A,A,B,C,A,B,B,C|
|  1| 20|A,C,B,C,A,B,B,C|
|  2| 26|X,Y,Z,C,A,B,B,C|
+---+---+---------------+
```

Please note that I can make it work by

```
>>> df2 = spark.sql('''select id,age, split(concat_ws(',', one, two),',') as three from df''')
```

But just wondering why the first approach is not working.

Answer (score 1):

[concat_ws](https://web.archive.org/web/20210208145651/https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.concat_ws) creates a single string column and not an array:

```py
df.select(F.size(df.one)).show()
df2.select(F.size(df2.three)).show()
```

Output:

```
+---------+
|size(one)|
+---------+
|        4|
|        4|
|        4|
|        4|
+---------+
+-----------+
|size(three)|
+-----------+
|          1|
|          1|
|          1|
|          1|
+-----------+
```

That means your array has just one element:

```py
df2.select(df2.three.getItem(0)).show()
df2.select(df2.three.getItem(1)).show()
df2.printSchema()
```

Output:

```
+---------------+
|       three[0]|
+---------------+
|A,B,B,C,A,B,B,C|
|A,A,B,C,A,B,B,C|
|A,C,B,C,A,B,B,C|
|X,Y,Z,C,A,B,B,C|
+---------------+

+--------+
|three[1]|
+--------+
|    null|
|    null|
|    null|
|    null|
+--------+

root
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- age: long (nullable = true)
 |-- three: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = false)
```

So what you actually should use, is [concat](https://web.archive.org/web/20210208145651/https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.concat) on spark >= 2.4:

```py
df3 = spark.sql('''select id,age, concat(one, two) as three from df''')
df3.show(truncate=False)
df3.printSchema()
df3.select(df3.three.getItem(0)).show()
df3.select(df3.three.getItem(1)).show()
```

Output:

```
+---+---+------------------------+
|id |age|three                   |
+---+---+------------------------+
|1  |25 |[A, B, B, C, A, B, B, C]|
|1  |20 |[A, A, B, C, A, B, B, C]|
|1  |20 |[A, C, B, C, A, B, B, C]|
|2  |26 |[X, Y, Z, C, A, B, B, C]|
+---+---+------------------------+

root
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- age: long (nullable = true)
 |-- three: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)

+--------+
|three[0]|
+--------+
|       A|
|       A|
|       A|
|       X|
+--------+

+--------+
|three[1]|
+--------+
|       B|
|       A|
|       C|
|       Y|
+--------+
```

Concating two arrays with spark < 2.4 requires an udf (check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37284077/combine-pyspark-dataframe-arraytype-fields-into-single-arraytype-field/37284548#37284548) for an example).

Comment: You are partially right.  you cannot use `concat` with 2 arrays.  It expects StringType or BinaryType

Comment: Spark >= 2.4 allows array columns. What version of spark do you use? Spark < 2.4 requires the usage of an udf to concatenate arrays (check this answer for an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37284548/6664872)).

Comment: nice @cronoik but when i see dtypes of both dataframe created by `concat` and `concat_ws` they are same `('arr', 'array<string>')` . So why one one string and another is array. ?

Comment: @PIG Are you sure? They are both array<string> on my machine (Spark 2.4.1). I have added the output of .printSchema() to my answer. Can you please check it again?

Answer (score 0):

Example way to do this using a UDF:

```
arraycat = F.udf(lambda x,y : x + y, ArrayType(StringType()))
df = df.withColumn("combined", arraycat("one", "two"))
df = df.withColumn("combined", F.explode("combined"))
```