# PySpark equivalent of adding a constant array to a dataframe as column

Tags: arrays, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, runtimeexception

The below code works in Scala-Spark.

```scala
scala> val ar = Array("oracle", "java")
ar: Array[String] = Array(oracle, java)

scala> df.withColumn("tags", lit(ar)).show(false)
+------+---+----------+----------+--------------+
|name  |age|role      |experience|tags          |
+------+---+----------+----------+--------------+
|John  |25 |Developer |2.56      |[oracle, java]|
|Scott |30 |Tester    |5.2       |[oracle, java]|
|Jim   |28 |DBA       |3.0       |[oracle, java]|
|Mike  |35 |Consultant|10.0      |[oracle, java]|
|Daniel|26 |Developer |3.2       |[oracle, java]|
|Paul  |29 |Tester    |3.6       |[oracle, java]|
|Peter |30 |Developer |6.5       |[oracle, java]|
+------+---+----------+----------+--------------+
```

How do I get the same behavior in PySpark? I tried the below, but it doesn't work and throws Java error.

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import *

tag = ["oracle", "java"]
df2.withColumn("tags", lit(tag)).show()
```

> : java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type class java.util.ArrayList [oracle, java]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add a constant column in a Spark DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32788322/how-to-add-a-constant-column-in-a-spark-dataframe)

Comment: @blackbishop no that explains only scala.. not pyspark

Comment: In pyspark, you should be using `tag = [lit("oracle"), lit("java")]    df2.withColumn("tags", array(*tag)).show()` as explained in the accepted answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combine PySpark DataFrame ArrayType fields into single ArrayType field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37284077/combine-pyspark-dataframe-arraytype-fields-into-single-arraytype-field)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can import array from functions module

```
>>> from pyspark.sql.types import *
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import array

>>> tag=array(lit("oracle"),lit("java")
>>> df2.withColumn("tags",tag).show()
```

Tested below

```
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import array

>>> tag=array(lit("oracle"),lit("java"))
>>> 
>>> ranked.withColumn("tag",tag).show()
+------+--------------+----------+-----+----+----+--------------+               
|gender|    ethinicity|first_name|count|rank|year|           tag|
+------+--------------+----------+-----+----+----+--------------+
|  MALE|      HISPANIC|    JAYDEN|  364|   1|2012|[oracle, java]|
|  MALE|WHITE NON HISP|    JOSEPH|  300|   2|2012|[oracle, java]|
|  MALE|WHITE NON HISP|    JOSEPH|  300|   2|2012|[oracle, java]|
|  MALE|      HISPANIC|     JACOB|  293|   4|2012|[oracle, java]|
|  MALE|      HISPANIC|     JACOB|  293|   4|2012|[oracle, java]|
|  MALE|WHITE NON HISP|     DAVID|  289|   6|2012|[oracle, java]|
|  MALE|WHITE NON HISP|     DAVID|  289|   6|2012|[oracle, java]|
|  MALE|      HISPANIC|   MATTHEW|  279|   8|2012|[oracle, java]|
|  MALE|      HISPANIC|   MATTHEW|  279|   8|2012|[oracle, java]|
|  MALE|      HISPANIC|     ETHAN|  254|  10|2012|[oracle, java]|
|  MALE|      HISPANIC|     ETHAN|  254|  10|2012|[oracle, java]|
|  MALE|WHITE NON HISP|   MICHAEL|  245|  12|2012|[oracle, java]|
|  MALE|WHITE NON HISP|   MICHAEL|  245|  12|2012|[oracle, java]|
|  MALE|WHITE NON HISP|     JACOB|  242|  14|2012|[oracle, java]|
|  MALE|WHITE NON HISP|     JACOB|  242|  14|2012|[oracle, java]|
|  MALE|WHITE NON HISP|     MOSHE|  238|  16|2012|[oracle, java]|
|  MALE|WHITE NON HISP|     MOSHE|  238|  16|2012|[oracle, java]|
|  MALE|      HISPANIC|     ANGEL|  236|  18|2012|[oracle, java]|
|  MALE|      HISPANIC|     AIDEN|  235|  19|2012|[oracle, java]|
|  MALE|WHITE NON HISP|    DANIEL|  232|  20|2012|[oracle, java]|
+------+--------------+----------+-----+----+----+--------------+
only showing top 20 rows
```

Comment: just curious.. how to assign a python dictionary in the same way?

Comment: try with create_map() function

Comment: tag2= lit("{'a':1,'b':2}")
ranked.withColumn("tag",tag2).show()

Answer (score 3):

I found the below list comprehension to work

```
>>> arr=["oracle","java"]
>>> mp=[ (lambda x:lit(x))(x) for x in arr ]
>>> df.withColumn("mk",array(mp)).show()
+------+---+----------+----------+--------------+
|  name|age|      role|experience|            mk|
+------+---+----------+----------+--------------+
|  John| 25| Developer|      2.56|[oracle, java]|
| Scott| 30|    Tester|       5.2|[oracle, java]|
|   Jim| 28|       DBA|       3.0|[oracle, java]|
|  Mike| 35|Consultant|      10.0|[oracle, java]|
|Daniel| 26| Developer|       3.2|[oracle, java]|
|  Paul| 29|    Tester|       3.6|[oracle, java]|
| Peter| 30| Developer|       6.5|[oracle, java]|
+------+---+----------+----------+--------------+

>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is difference between `ar` declare in `scala` and `tag` declare in `python`. `ar` is `array` type but `tag` is `List` type and `lit` does not allow `List` that's why it is giving error.

You need to install `numpy` to declare `array` like below

```
import numpy as np
tag = np.array(("oracle","java"))
```

Just for reference if you use `List` in `scala`, it will also give error

```
scala> val ar = List("oracle","java")
ar: List[String] = List(oracle, java)

scala> df.withColumn("newcol", lit(ar)).printSchema
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type class scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon List(oracle, java)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Literal$.apply(literals.scala:78)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Literal$$anonfun$create$2.apply(literals.scala:164)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Literal$$anonfun$create$2.apply(literals.scala:164)
  at scala.util.Try.getOrElse(Try.scala:79)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Literal$.create(literals.scala:163)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.functions$.typedLit(functions.scala:127)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.functions$.lit(functions.scala:110)
```

Comment: no it is giving error..````tag=["oracle","java"];  tag2=np.array(tag)```` works but ````df.withColumn("tag",lit(tag2))```` again throws error

Comment: why are you using tag2=np.array(tag) you should use tag = np.array(("oracle","java")) as i had mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

**Spark 3.4+**

```py
F.lit(["oracle", "java"])
```

Full example:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = spark.range(5)
df = df.withColumn("tags", F.lit(["oracle", "java"]))

df.show()
# +---+--------------+
# | id|          tags|
# +---+--------------+
# |  0|[oracle, java]|
# |  1|[oracle, java]|
# |  2|[oracle, java]|
# |  3|[oracle, java]|
# |  4|[oracle, java]|
# +---+--------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

In the above answer are not appropriate.as  we are taking the array of literals .
In general for any  application we have list of items  in the below format and we cannot append that list directly to pyspark dataframe .we should iterate though each of the list item and then converting to literal and then passing the group of literals to  pyspark Array function so we can add this Array as new column to the pyspark dataframe. Hope the below code helps

```
from pyspark.sql.types import * 
import pyspark.sql.functions as F 
import numpy as np 
arr1 = np.array(["oracle","java"]) 
print(arr1) <br>
df_test = spark.createDataFrame(data=[('finance',10),('marketing',20),('sales',30),('IT',40)],schema=['deptname','deptid']) <br>
df_test = df_test.withColumn("tags",F.array([F.lit(item) for item in arr1]))<br>
df_test.show(truncate=False)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The above is correct as per the question asked. please check and upvote it